# Joining Linux machine to Active directory

Tags: linux, active-directory

What would be the benefit of joining a Linux machine to windows AD, let's say I already manage the users on this Linux machine from the AD, my question is more about the pros and cons of adding the Linux **machine** object to AD.

What would be the impact from management, security, audit, remote control or other services over the Linux **machine** joined by the Windows Active Directory?